# VPN between Oracle Cloud and Azure

Tags: oracle, azure, cloud, oracle-call-interface

I'm trying to setup a S2S VPN connection between Oracle Cloud and Azure. I am able to get the connection up and it is connected on both ends. After around an hour the Oracle Cloud side dies and the IP-sec status is down on the Oracle side. The Azure side is still in connected state.

I suspected some issue with the IPsec policy so i have played around with different policies but all with the same result. 
*The connection comes up, and dies on Oracle side after around an hour.*

I have cross references the settings with both IPsec config support matrixes.
https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Reference/supportedIPsecparams.htm
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-compliance-crypto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reached out to OCI support and they got this PFS2 Group changed from Group5 on the OCI side within 2hrs. Granted it takes almost 20mins to open up a ticket with all of the OCID info but the Sev1 Team got it done quick.

Answer (score 1):

We are able to fix the issue by updating the PFS group to 2 Oracle side.

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to Oracle and they managed to change the setting for Perfect Forward Secrecy 
 (PFS) to support the preferred Azure PFS setting (PFS 2). This stabilized the connection.